# label containing a-href-tag doesn't trigger it's input

Tags: css, radio-button, label

I have a label containing an a-href-tag:

```
<input id="sn_menu01_close" class="sn_menu_close" name="sn_menu" type="radio">

<p><label for="sn_menu01_close" class="close">angebot<a href="#angebot">Angebot und Preise</a></label></p>
```

When clicking the link the corresponding radiobutton doesn't trigger. When clicking the text outside the link it works. How can I make it work for the link too? Both have to work, triggering the radio button and skipping to the links destination (anchor).
I'm looking for a pure-CSS solution, using javascript or jQuery it's no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to trigger it with jQuery function:

```js
$('input[type="radio"] ~ p label a').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var radio = $(this).parent().attr('for');
  $('#' + radio).prop("checked", true);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="sn_menu01_close" class="sn_menu_close" name="sn_menu" type="radio">

<p>
  <label for="sn_menu01_close" class="close">angebot<a href="#angebot">Angebot und Preise</a></label>
</p>
```

**EDITED for Pure CSS:**
Try to use `pointer-events: none` to disable the link:

```css
input[type="radio"] ~ p label a { 
    pointer-events: none
}
```

```html
<input id="sn_menu01_close" class="sn_menu_close" name="sn_menu" type="radio">

<p>
  <label for="sn_menu01_close" class="close">angebot<a href="#angebot">Angebot und Preise</a></label>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for this hint, but sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm looking for a pure CSS solution.

Comment: Ok, I have added pure css solution in my answer

Comment: This works as far as the radio button is checked now. But unfortunately the link is no more active, it doesn't skip to the anchor.